# Adding numbers in a notification icon

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

I implemented a notification system to my Android application and I would like to know if is there any way to set the Small Icon as a number/text. Because in my notification I want to display the number of new orders that the user has in the small icon field. Is there anyway to do that without involving a lot of different images with different numbers and combining them to generate any number?

This is my pushNotification method:

```
public void PushNotification()
    {
        NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext());
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainScreen.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),0,notificationIntent,0);

        //set
        builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.chef_hat);
        Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.chef_hat);
        builder.setLargeIcon(largeIcon);

        builder.setContentText("Click here to open the app.");
        //Uri uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
        //builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);

        System.out.println("Subtraction: " + (auxiliar1 - auxiliar2));

        if (auxiliar1 - auxiliar2 == 1) {
            builder.setContentTitle("You have a new order!");
        } else if ((auxiliar1 - auxiliar2) > 1){
            builder.setContentTitle("You have " + (auxiliar1 - auxiliar2) + " new orders!");
        } else {
            builder.setContentTitle("You have a new order!");
        }

        auxiliar1 = 0;
        auxiliar2 = TabLayoutScreenActivity.orderSizeFixed;

        if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=21) {
            builder.setColor(Color.parseColor("#D8540D"));
        }
        builder.setAutoCancel(true);
        //builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);
        long[] v = {500,1000};
        builder.setVibrate(v);
        if (PrefernceHelper.getString(MainScreen.this, Commons.Constants.NOTIFICATION_SOUD) == null) {
            Uri uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
            builder.setSound(uri);
        }
        else {
            builder.setSound(Uri.parse(PrefernceHelper.getString(MainScreen.this, Commons.Constants.NOTIFICATION_SOUD)));
        }

        Notification notification = builder.build();
        nm.notify((int)System.currentTimeMillis(),notification);
    }
```

Comment: please post your code

Comment: I just posted my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is none trivial. At the moment I believe there are hooks for clocks and calendar based values that can alter icons based on time or date.

Some devs have had luck manually changing the icon by building a new bitmap, however it's hit and miss whether these new icon will be picked up by the launcher without a reboot.

I would suggest creating a widget for your app instead!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try to create a widget then.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you're asking about then notification icon not the launcher icon.

If you're asking about the notification icon, go here
https://www.skoumal.com/en/android-how-draw-text-bitmap/

I do recommend to use your bitmap as part of setLargeIcon method since the small icon is used as a app's notification icon.

```
// notification icon
builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification); 

//you can use custom icon
Bitmap largeIcon = createMyCustomIconWithNumber();
builder.setLargeIcon(largeIcon);
```

if you're asking about launcher icon, go here.
https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger